# What is the use of the nested pointer type in iterator_traits?

Tags: c++, iterator, traits, proxy-classes, boost-iterators

The `std::iterator_traits` class template defines 5 nested types: `iterator_category`, `value_type`, `difference_type`, `pointer` and `reference`. Browsing the sources of the `<algorithm>` header of both libc++ and libstdc++, one can see many uses of `value_type`, `difference_type` and `iterator_category`, but only one for `reference` (inside `std::iter_swap`) and none for `pointer`.

My application uses a hand-built proxy iterator / proxy reference pair. I want to transition to using the Boost `iterator_facade` which lets me configure the reference type from the default `T&` to an arbitrary type, but not so for the pointer type which is `T*` by default. I want to avoid being bitten by some deeply hidden use of the nested `pointer` type.

**Note**: the iterator is a proxy for a builtin type without nested members, so I do not need compatibility with `operator->` (for which the return type would be `pointer`).

**Question**: what use cases are there in the Standard Library for the nested type `pointer` inside `iterator_traits`?

Comment: I found no uses in the original SGI STL or in the C++ standard. Probably provided as a means for the language user to use it, not the standard library.

Comment: You may find its declared type interesting in an iterator who's template type is specialized by `<T*>` It is still `T*`, but `T` everywhere else loses the `*`.

Comment: @WhozCraig tnx good point, but if I would just declare `using pointer = void` for my own iterator, where could I get bitten?

Comment: It is used by reverse_iterator to find the return type of operator-> for instance.

Comment: That I cannot tell you. Is your iterator an output iterator ? If so, the standard says it can be defined as `void`, otherwise it shall be defined properly. (again, this is for `iterator_traits` so I can't comment on boost's template, as i'm unfamiliar with it).

Comment: Note that in C++11 `reference` is mostly useless since you can look at `decltype(*it)`. Looking at `it->` seems harder :-(

Comment: @MarcGlisse My proxy iterator is bidirectional, and if I define `pointer` somehow, `reverse_iterator` can extract it so as to comply with the iterator requirements. But I can't find any actual *usage* of the `pointer` type in any standard algorithm. The default is `T*`, output iterators can set it to `void`, and as long as you don't need `operator->` (which I don't) there seems no harm in setting it to `void` or any other arbitrary type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In contrast to the first three types `iterator_category`, `value_type` and `difference_type`  (which are heavily used by the standard algorithms for tag dispatching to efficient versions depending on the iterator capabilities) the last two types `pointer` and `reference` inside `iterator_traits` appear not to be used by any algorithms but are used to define compliance with the iterator requirements.

**24.2.1 In general [iterator.requirements.general]**

> 1 [..] All iterators `i` for which the expression `(*i).m` is
>   well-deﬁned, support the expression `i->m` with the same semantics as
>   `(*i).m`. [...]

**24.4.1 Iterator traits [iterator.traits]**

> [...]
>   In addition, the types
>
> ```
>  iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference
>  iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer
> ```
>
> shall be deﬁned as the iterator’s
>   reference and pointer types, that is, for an iterator object `a`, the
>   same type as the type of `*a` and `a->`, respectively. [...]

The default values `T*` and `T&` for `pointer` and `reference` of course satisfy the iterator requirements. Regarding proxy references, the [Boost.Iterator documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#id2) specifies

> The `reference` type of a readable iterator (and today's input iterator)
>   need not in fact be a reference, so long as it is convertible to the
>   iterator's `value_type`. When the `value_type` is a class, however, it
>   must still be possible to access members through `operator->`.
>   Therefore, an iterator whose `reference` type is not in fact a reference
>   must return a proxy containing a copy of the referenced value from its
>   `operator->`.
>
> The return types for `iterator_facade`'s `operator->` and `operator[]` are
>   not explicitly specified. Instead, those types are described in terms
>   of a set of requirements, which must be satisfied by the
>   `iterator_facade` implementation.

**Conclusion**: as long as a proxy iterator does not require accessing members of its underlying `value_type` through `.m` or `->m`, one does not need to worry about the `pointer` type inside `iterator_traits`, and even if one does use proxy iterators, `boost::iterator_facade` will do the right thing.